# adding icons of thumbs up and comment: best option

Tags: rating, comments, like

I would like to add the icons of likes and comments inside a CQWP or CSWP. Kind of like the following

http://fontawesome.io/icon/thumbs-up/
http://fontawesome.io/icon/comment/

I do not want to pay for them so I wonder if similar icons are already somewhere in sharepoint that I can link (sharepoint online) or I can use something already in my possession such as the Wingdings or webdings that are in every computer with MS Office. In case you provide an icon that is free of charge, where do I place it to link it in the template file.

Answer (score 1):

#### Fabric

Instead of Bootstrap/Fontawesome Microsoft has **(Office UI) Fabric**

- https://dev.office.com/fabric#/styles/icons

which has

[image]

Used within a Microsoft application it is free

(Like FontAwesome) You need to load the Fabric.css file, then you can use HTML:

```
<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Like"></i>
```

#### Emoji

Another option is to use Emoji, an easy copy/paste, but they display different on devices

- http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

[image]

[You can select the character below, and copy/paste]

Emojis are standardized characters, most modern browsers can handle them, So they are characters just like any other. No need for CSS files, no need for Images. You select the emoji (double click on it is the easiest) Then do Ctrl-C Ctrl-V

Comment: in case i want to use the emoji, what do I need to do? 'download' the png image? I do not understand copy/paste in this context

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: I need to use them in a custom template of CQWP or CSWP, not paste them in a page. Where do I place them? inside a picture library? and how do I get them in PNG format or other useful format?

Comment: They are not images.. they are **characters**.. just like a, b, c ,d